# use ajax load the entire html for multiple user application?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

how to load user's data from db to php to ajax and then manipulate the DOM?

here's what is in my mind :

user logged in -> fetch user data from db with php -> ajax request all the data using post -> do something on DOM

how the ajax look like? I only know how to use this to do from ajax to php to db :

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "send.php",
      data: { item : text }
})
```

Comment: what do you mean "ajax request all the data using post"?

Answer (score 0):

You can do your backend operation in send.php, then you can return the html data from the backend

Eg. In send.php

```
echo "<h2>" . $your_db_thing . "</h2>";
```

In ajax, add success settings,refer [Jquery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "send.php",
      data: { item : text },
      success:function(data) { // data will be <h2>your_db_thing</h2>
            $('#successDiv').html(data); // the success element in which your html to be placed
      }
})
```